# Add parameter to URL which may or may not have query parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL that could be any of the following (or more):

```
http://www.mysite.com/some/url
http://www.mysite.com/some/url?a=b
http://www.mysite.com/some/url?a=b&c=d
```

I want an easy way to append a another value to the end, for example "e=f. So that in each case I would end up with:

```
http://www.mysite.com/some/url?e=f
http://www.mysite.com/some/url?a=b&e=f
http://www.mysite.com/some/url?a=b&c=d&e=f
```

What is the easiest way to do this. The following will not work for all cases:

```
var url = 'http://www.mysite.com/some/url';
var newQuery = 'e=f';
url += '?' + newQuery;
```

Is there something built into Jquery that could handle parsing URLs and adding parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a query string if you don't have it (or) appends to the existing one if you have one already.

```
var url = 'http://www.mysite.com/some/url?a=b';
var newQuery = 'e=f';
url += ((url.indexOf('?') != -1) ? '&' : '?') + newQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
var url = 'http://www.mysite.com/some/url';
var newQuery = 'e=f';
url += (url.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : ' &') + newQuery;
```

This will check with `indexOf` if `?` isn't in the URL and add the `?` otherwise the `&` + your `newQuery`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Have newQueries always be an array, if it's empty - just use the url, if not - append the values.

```
var url = 'http://www.mysite.com/some/url';
var newQueries = ['e=f', 's=e', 'x=y'];
url += newQueries.length && '?' + newQueries.join('&');
```

Comment: Problem is, the URL is the part that might change. It could be anything. I want a way of APPENDING a new query parameter, without breaking the url.

Answer (score 0):

take your additional parameters in an array variable with string elements and add these 
variables to ur url

dynamically update array and add parameters

example:

var additional_params = ['e=f', 's=e']

if additional_params.length != 0

"http://www.mysite.com/some/url?" + additional_params.join('&')